# Android - Add new library to repo?

Tags: android, git, repository

I'm trying to add a new library to the android platform, but when I run the "repo status" command, the folder in which my library is located does not show up as added.

If for example my library is called foo, I created a folder /external/foo and placed my library code in it.  This foo folder is not seen by the "repo status" command.  Is there some way I need to manually add it to the working tree?

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add it to your $ANDROID_TREE/.repo/manifest.xml. For ex:

```
<remote fetch="git://git.myrepo.org/" name="myrepo" review="review.myrepo.org"/>

<project name="platform/external/speex" remote="myrepo" path="external/speex" revision="9965152ae52eb4dfdafbdcd8b55e39d1a23052e0"/>
```

for more info:

```
repo help manifest
```

Also manifest.xml tends to be a symbolic link to a manifest in a git repo, so keep that in mind.